# Is there a Windows Registry "dictionary" that explains the whole (or most of) the Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, registry

I'd like to be able to see what registry keys are used for. A book on the registry would be fine as well. Info on Windows Vista changes would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, how I wish there was a single site where the registry was collectively documented by all who write values there! Keep in mind, any app can create its own set of registry keys and values, so it's not just MS who would be necessary to such an effort. Though they would be a key player!

In the meantime, there are two MS sites I use as startng points when I need to know what a particular key/value pair do:

Windows 2003 registry reference: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778196.aspx

Windows 2000 Registry reference:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974061.aspx](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/default.mspx)

Keep in mind that since Windows is an evolving thing, even information about older versions can be very helpful. Also note that W2003 bears a lot of resemblance to XP. Sadly, I have not found a link to the Vista/Windows 2008 registries similar to the above.

When you need to know what's up with a specific key, and it's not found in one of the above links, try a search of that key's full path at http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: It seems MS stopped publishing these references for later versions of Windows. Can't find anything like this for modern versions, unfortunately. Many of the ones in the 2003 reference are still relevant, but I assume there are many new ones that are undocumented.

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia article is actually rather nice. Not a full account of everything, but not too shabby either.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry

Answer (score 2):

Always look up APIs in the Windows SDK first instead of registry entries first . For example, if you store the path to the user's my document folder (yes it is in registery), your code may break when the user's registery roams to another machine where the user's profile is stored in a different location.

Suggested reading:
[The long and sad story of the Shell Folders key](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this help file](http://www.majorgeeks.com/Mystery_Behind_Windows_Registry_d415.html) in the past. Very good resource

Comment: That help file is a little bit dated (2002) and seems to refer a lot to Windows 95 (suggesting that it's even more out of date than 2002) but it is informative.